# Visual Studio Code - No such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with Visual Studio Code. I want to code with Python. I have installed the newest version of Python. I have installed Python extension on Visual Studio Code. I create file with .py extension (sample.py) and write first line of code to se if it's working.

so I write:

print("lalalalala")

and the result in terminal was:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\Python> & D:/Python/python.exe c:/Users/Micha/Desktop/Python/sample.py
D:\Python\python.exe: can't open file 'c:/Users/Micha/Desktop/Python/sample.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\Python>

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you double-checked your file paths? It looks like you're calling both Python and your script with the fully-qualified file path - if you've told python to look someplace where the file doesn't exist, this error will occur

Comment: Also check the permissions on the file.

Answer (score -2):

you have to install python and write the file name with the extention .py

Comment: Michal already mentioned, he installed python and the file has the *.py* extension. If you would like to help try to reproduce it and be proactive.